# PHP/SQL script only works sometimes

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a PHP form that seems to only want to work sometimes. I really don't understand what is wrong with it or why. I will submit test data successfully, but 5 minutes later I will do another test and I get the error message.

I'm not an PHP or SQL expert so help me out!

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="user"; // Mysql username
$password="pass"; // Mysql password
$db_name="database"; // Database name
$tbl_name="table"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Get values from form
$title=$_POST['title'];
$body=$_POST['body'];
$date=$_POST['date'];
$tags=$_POST['tags'];

// Insert data into mysql
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(title, body, date, tags)VALUES('$title', '$body', '$date', '$tags')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful".
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='insert.php'>Back to main page</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?>

<?php
// close connection
mysql_close();
?>
```

Thank you!
Louie

Comment: Consider `mysqli` or `PDO` with prepared statements. It's possible you have "unintentional" SQL injection depending on your $_POST values.

Comment: Try `$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());` to show error message

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's. Which is why it is important to consider taking the mobile-first approach to ' at line 1

Comment: Ok I removed the apostrophe in the workd "PC's" so it reads "PCs" which allowed me to make a submission. How could I fix that? mysqli?

Answer (score 0):

For first enable error reporting:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

And check what's going on in your code.

Maybe problem is not in PHP but in MySQL Server.